# URL Rewrite Pattern to exclude application name from path

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use the IIS 7 URL Rewrite feature for the first time, and I'm having trouble getting my regular expression working. It seems like it should be simple enough. All I need to do is rewrite a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/myApplication/MySpecialFolder
```

To:

```
http://localhost/MySpecialFolder
```

Is this possible? I want the regular expression to ignore everything before "myApplication" in the original URL, so that I could use "http://localhost" OR "http://mysite", etc.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
^myApplication/MySpecialFolder$
```

But using the "Test Pattern..." feature in IIS, it says my patterns don't match unless I supply "myApplication/MySpecialFolder" exactly. Does anyone know how I can update my regular expression so that everything prior to "myApplication" is ignored and the following URLs will be seen as a match?

```
http://localhost/myApplication/MySpecialFolder
http://mysite/myApplication/MySpecialFolder
```

Many thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION:**

I needed to change my regex to:

```
myApplication/MySpecialFolder
```

Without the `^` at the beginning and without the `$` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is correct, the pattern will be matched against path starting after the first slash after the domain.
So only bold part will be used for matching: `http://localhost/`**myApplication/MySpecialFolder**

To limit the rewriting to specific domain you have to use `Conditions` section with `Condition input` = `{HTTP_HOST}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is this a better solution than @EvilBob22's solution above? That seems to do the trick, but I'll need to find a way now to create back-references to everything that came before and after my string so that I can rewrite it like `{R:1}MySpecialFolder{R:2}`. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you need regex like: (.*)MySpecialFolder(.*) and then rewrite as you mentioned above.

Comment: Good point, the original I submitted only matches, it doesn't "save" what it finds.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work and testing the pattern shows that my back-references are correct as well. Should I be able to now navigate to `http://localhost/myApplication/MySpecialFolder/test.aspx` and see that it rewrites the URL as `http://localhost/MySpecialFolder.aspx`? Or is there more to it? Because right now, nothing is happening.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your requirement, to get example above working you don't need to capture (back-reference) anything, just use `http://localhost/MySpecialFolder.aspx` in action.

Comment: Ultimately, what I want to happen is when someone goes to `http://localhost/myApplication/MySpecialFolder/test.aspx` for the URL to show up like `http://localhost/MySpecialFolder/test.aspx`

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is something radically different with regexes in IIS, you would want to take out the anchor (`^`) at the beginning to match.

```
myApplication/MySpecialFolder$
```

The carat `^` tells it that that is the beginning of the string and the dollar sign `$` tells it to match the end.  A regex like `abc` finds "abc" anywhere in the string, `^abc` matches strings that start with "abc", `abc$` matches strings that end with "abc", and `^abc$` only matches when the whole string is "abc".

Comment: Wow. I was close! Hah, I also needed to take off the `$` because I also need to ignore everything after "MySpecialFolder" as well. Thanks for the help!